# Material-UI: is it possible to send an object through a MenuItem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to send an object `{ language: "english", code: "en" }` through a MUI `<MenuItem />`. If there is a way to successfully implement this? It would save me a lot of busy work creating massive switch statements down the line assigning codes to languages.

Current implement with me trying to pass an object as the first selection:

```
        <FormControlSelection variant="outlined">
          <InputLabel id="select-language">Language</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="select-language"
            value={lesson.language.language}
            name="language"
            label="Language"
            onChange={handleLanguage}
          >
            <MenuItem value={{ language: "english", code: "en" }}>
              English
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"italian"}>Italian</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={"spanish"}>Spanish</MenuItem>
          </Select>
          <FormHelperText>What language is the file in?</FormHelperText>
        </FormControlSelection>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to implement the solution provided above I get the following warning in my console:

> Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select (name="language") component.
> Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
> The available values are '[object Object]', 'italian', 'spanish'.

In this example the value *does* make it to my state ... I have the object successfully updating there for languages ... **but** my input appears as an empty select as shown below ...

[image]

any thoughts?

Comment: See my related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668206/material-ui-select-is-not-applying-the-default-selections/56671185#56671185

Comment: One possibility is to create an object/map with language-code pairs and access it when needed (in `handleLanguage`). No switch statements required.